# oracle cursor for updating column data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

i want oracle cursor for updating `ENTITY_BRANCH`.table1 from  `BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE`.table2 based on `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` in both tables
if i have more than 200000 employees in both tables ...

the table1 which i want to update look like

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER    JOINING_DATE      ENTITY_BRANCH 

     12              11/12/2006          null
     13              01/11/2009          null
```

table2 for updating from look like  ::

```
 Employee_Number   MINISTRY_CODE   BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE

        12                 333                 30
        13                 222                 31
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the rows one-by-one, or in batches, in a cursor loop? Why not do a single correlated update statement - it will be faster and simpler, and 200,000 rows isn't really very many.

Comment: one by one i meant

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a subquery:

```
update ENTITY_BRANCH.table1 t
    set ENTITY_BRANCH = (SELECT t2.BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE
                         FROM BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE.table2 t2
                         WHERE t2.Employee_Number = t.Employee_Number
                        );
```

There is no need for a cursor to do this.  On the other hand, an index on `table2(Employee_Number, BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE)` would be very helpful.

Comment: update ENTITY_BRANCH.EMPLOYMENTS t1
    set ENTITY_BRANCH = (SELECT t2.BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE
                         FROM BRANCH_SECRETARIAT_CODE.MERGE_RIO_TABLES t2
                         WHERE t2.Employee_Number = t.Employee_Number
                        );

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @Ali . . . They are your table names.  That is something you have to fix.

Comment: this tables name correct 100 % brother am using even toad fro run this subquery

Comment: @ALI . . . On closer inspection, there was a small typo in the query.